# How to run lint differently on Node with Typescript?

Tags: node.js, eslint

I am looking for a way to display lint errors in the console as Create-React-App does. I have achieved it but with two npm scripts. I want to reduce it to just one, but with this script `eslint . --ext .ts && node ./build/index.js` I get the following error:

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.11.0

No files matching the pattern "&&" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
```

Anything I put there is taken as part of the eslint command.

My current solution is this:

```
"dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"npm run serve\"",
"serve": "eslint . --ext .ts && node --trace-deprecation --trace-warnings ./build/index.js",
```

It works just fine, but I find it a bit redundant. Is there any way to make it just one command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that both parts of your `serve` are things you'd likely want to use in other contexts too, why not extract them? For example:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"npm run serve\"",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "serve": "npm run lint && npm start",
    "start": "node ./build/index.js"
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can use the built-in `pre` script prefix to lint before serving:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"npm run serve\"",
    "preserve": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "serve": "node ./build/index.js"
  }
}
```

Another convention would be to have individual steps with a `task:step` name, e.g. `"serve": "npm run serve:lint && npm run serve:start"`; I've written a bit about NPM automation [on my blog](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2019/Feb/10/automation-for-the-people.html).